# ElastiCache Redis Cluster and Istio

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, istio, redis-cluster, amazon-eks

I'm trying to connect to my ElastiCache Redis Cluster 5.0 from within a container in EKS that has Istio as a sidecar proxy but I constantly get MOVED error-loop.

I have 1 shard with 2 replicas and I have added a ServiceEntry and a VirtualService for each of the shards + the configuration endpoint.

Example config used for Istio routing:

```
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: redis-test-cluster
spec:
  hosts:
  - redis-cluster-test.XXXX.clustercfg.euw1.cache.amazonaws.com
  ports:
  - number: 6379
    name: tcp
    protocol: TCP
  resolution: NONE
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
---
```

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: redis-test-cluster
spec:
  hosts:
  - redis-cluster-test.XXXX.clustercfg.euw1.cache.amazonaws.com
  http:
  - timeout: 30s
    route:
    - destination:
        host: redis-cluster-test.XXXX.clustercfg.euw1.cache.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that Redis protocol is not HTTP, so you cannot use an `http` VirtualService.

To control egress access for a TCP protocol like Redis, check [Egress Control for TLS section of the Consuming External MongoDB Services blog post](https://preliminary.istio.io/blog/2018/egress-mongo/#egress-control-for-tls).

Comment: But my connection to the Redis cluster does not happen over TLS. There is no encryption in transit so how would that work?

I also did remove the `VirtualService` and there was still a connection but from time to time the MOVED loop happens.

Comment: If so, check this section https://preliminary.istio.io/blog/2018/egress-mongo/#egress-control-for-tcp

Comment: An alternative is https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/#direct-access-to-external-services or in the latest version
https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/#install-istio-with-access-to-all-external-services-by-default

Comment: So the only option is to enable encryption in transit or allow all egress traffic?

Comment: Three options:
1. Apply TLS
2. Use CIDR IP ranges
3. Allow all egress traffic